# "rails generate" creates new "generate" project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running the command generates new rails projects:

```
$ rails generate controller home index
```

The above will create four new rails projects: *generate*, *controller*, *home*, and *index*\

Why is this happening?

I'm using rails (2.3.5)

Comment: I have the same thing happening with me. I am using rails 3 :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess, you are trying to use [Rails 3](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html#script-replaced-by-scriptrails) syntax for a Rails 2 app.

You should use [`script/generate`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails) in Rails 2.

Answer (score 4):

```
rails generate ...
```

creates a Rails project called "generate"

Use this instead:

```
ruby script/generate controller home index
```